# Readers that support EPUB 3 page numbers

Tags: epub, table-of-contents

We are adding page numbers to our epubs according to the spec defined [here](http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/xhtml/pagenum.php).
We would like to test this functionality though, are there any readers that support page numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display page numbers in iBooks. Just be sure to select the "Tap to show printed page numbers" option in the toc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Infinity Reader.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imeonsoft.infinity 
It shows page numbers as well as audio, video and all ePub3 features. The reader comes with a free book, which contains youtube video.
Moreover, you can download a lot of free books.